# Error in <servlet-mapping> <url-pattern> in web.xml in Eclipse Helios for Java EE developers

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am providing an attribute() in  in web.xml which is

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVCTutorial</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but I am getting an error "The word 'htm' is not correctly spelled". Please let me know if I am making a mistake.

Thank you,
Sid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably a warning. Ignore it.

Answer (score 10):

Your XML file is fine. You can just ignore the warning and run it.

Since this Eclipse's builtin XML spellchecker can lead to big annoyments, I'd suggest to just disable it. Go to *Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling* and untick the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: @Sid - you'd better accept BalusC answer. It will save you further headaches as well ;)